# Asymptotic Standard Error of Estimator that is a Function of Two Samples

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

> Suppose that $X_1,...,X_m$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ are independent exponential random variables with $X_i\sim EXP(\lambda)$ and $Y_j\sim EXP(\theta \lambda)$.  This implies that $E(X_i)=1/\lambda$ and $E(Y_j)=1/{\lambda\theta}$.
>
> Let $\hat\theta_{m,n}$ be the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.  Find an expression for the approximate standard error of $\hat\theta_{m,n}$.  Assume that $m$ and $n$ are large and use asymptotic theory.

I end up calculating that the MLE is $\hat\theta_{m,n}=\frac{\bar X}{\bar Y}$, where X and Y bar are just the sample means of the respective distributions.  I'm not one hundred percent confident in this, but it seems right.

So from here, I need to find the variance of this expression; particularly, the limiting variance; but here's the issue; this MLE depends on both $m$ and $n$!  In my experience, I've never had to manipulate an MLE like this; so the typical way to do this (when you have just one sample and one parameter):

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta-\theta)\to^d N(0,I_1^{-1}(\theta))$$

doesn't make sense any more!  Or at least, not to me.  So how can I possibly "find an expression for the approximate standard error of $\hat\theta_{m,n}$?"

Comment: How do the $X_i$ variables have any relevance to $\theta$?

Comment: I see your point; so should it simply be left as an expression of m?  If so, why would it say "assume that $m$ is large?"

Comment: I think you'll find that the $x_i$ variables are relevant insofar as they give information on $\lambda$, which then assists in estimation of $\theta$ through the $y_i$ variables.  When you write out the likelihood function and calculate the MLE, it is a function of both sets of observed values (the form given by the OP is correct).

Comment: @Ben : It is not clear what is given info and what is to be estimated.  It looks like $\lambda$ is a known constant, whereas $\theta$ is to be estimated.  Though, in that case the $\{X_i\}$ values are irrelevant, so likely your interpretation is the intended one.  It would not hurt for the problem to be clarified.

Comment: @Michael, the lambda is not a known constant in this context; this I am certain of.

Comment: One approximation might $1/Z \approx \frac{1}{E[Z]} + \frac{-1}{E[Z]^2}(Z-E[Z]) + \frac{2}{2!E[Z]^3}(Z-E[Z])^2$, so $$ E[1/Z] \approx \frac{1}{E[Z]}+ \frac{Var(Z)}{E[Z]^3}$$

Comment: @Michael, what does Z represent in this context?

Comment: You can use it as $Z=\overline{Y}$, as in 

$$E\left[\frac{\overline{X}}{\overline{Y}}\right] = \underbrace{E\left[\overline{X}\right]}_{1/\lambda}E\left[\frac{1}{\overline{Y}}\right] \approx (1/\lambda)\left[\frac{1}{E\left[\overline{Y}\right]} + \frac{Var\left(\overline{Y}\right)}{E\left[\overline{Y}\right]^3}\right]$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723035/321264

Answer (score 1):

**Checking the MLE:** From your specification of the problem, your log-likelihood function is:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathcal{l}_{\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}}(\theta, \lambda) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^m \ln p (x_i | \lambda) + \sum_{i=1}^n \ln p (y_i | \theta, \lambda) \\[8pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^m (\ln \lambda - \lambda x_i) + \sum_{i=1}^n (\ln \theta + \ln \lambda - \theta \lambda y_i) \\[8pt]
&= m ( \ln \lambda - \lambda \bar{x} ) + n ( \ln \theta + \ln \lambda - \theta \lambda \bar{y}).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This gives the score functions:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}_{\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}}}{\partial \theta}(\theta, \lambda) 
&= n \Big( \frac{1}{\theta} - \lambda \bar{y} \Big), \\[8pt]
\frac{\partial \mathcal{l}_{\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y}}}{\partial \lambda}(\theta, \lambda) 
&= m \Big( \frac{1}{\lambda} - \bar{x} \Big) + n \Big( \frac{1}{\lambda} - \theta \bar{y} \Big).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Setting both partial derivatives to zero and solving the resulting score equations yields the MLEs:

$$\hat{\theta}_{m,n} = \frac{\bar{x}}{\bar{y}} \quad \quad \quad \hat{\lambda}_{m,n} = \frac{1}{\bar{x}}.$$

(Note that in the case where $\bar{y} = 0$ the first of the score equations is strictly positive and so the MLE for $\theta$ does not exist.)  This confirms your calculations of the MLE.

---

**Adjusting the MLE to remove bias:** Treating the MLE as a random variable we have:

$$\hat{\theta}_{m,n} = \frac{n}{m} \cdot \frac{\dot{X}}{\dot{Y}},$$

where $\dot{X} \equiv m \bar{X} \sim \text{Gamma} (m, \lambda)$ and $\dot{Y} \equiv n \bar{Y} \sim \text{Gamma} (n, \theta \lambda)$ are independent random variables.  From this equation, the MLE is a scaled [beta-prime random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution):

$$\hat{\theta}_{m,n} \sim \theta \cdot \frac{n}{m} \cdot \text{Beta-Prime}(m, n).$$

This estimator has expected value $\mathbb{E} (\hat{\theta}_{m,n}) = \frac{n}{n-1} \cdot \theta$, which means that it has positive bias.  We can correct this bias by using the bias-adjusted MLE:

$$\tilde{\theta}_{m,n} = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{\bar{X}}{\bar{Y}} \sim \theta \cdot \frac{n-1}{m} \cdot \text{Beta-Prime}(m, n).$$

---

**Standard-Error of the adjusted MLE:** The adjusted MLE is unbiased.  It has variance:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{V}(\tilde{\theta}_{m,n}) 
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \Big( \theta \cdot \frac{n-1}{m} \cdot r - \theta \Big)^2 \text{Beta-Prime} ( r | m, n) dr \\[8pt]
&= \theta^2 \cdot \frac{\Gamma(m) \Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)} \int \limits_0^\infty \Big( 1 - \frac{n-1}{m} \cdot r \Big)^2 r^{m-1} ( 1 + r )^{-m-n} dr \\[8pt]
&= \theta^2 \cdot \frac{n+m-1}{m(n-2)}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The corresponding standard error is:

$$\text{se}(\tilde{\theta}_{m,n}) = \tilde{\theta}_{m,n} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{n+m-1}{m(n-2)}}.$$

Letting $\phi \equiv m/n$ and taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we obtain the asymptotic approximation:

$$\text{se}(\tilde{\theta}_{m,n}) \approx \frac{\tilde{\theta}_{m,n}}{\sqrt{n-2}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1+\phi}{\phi}}.$$

This gives you both exact and approximate expressions for the standard error.  I hope that is helpful.  (Please make sure to review my algebra to make sure I haven't made a mistake!)

Comment: Likely your use of $m$ and $n$ is switched in the $\dot{X}$ and $\dot{Y}$ definitions.

Comment: Can you show me where?

Comment: You have $\dot{X} = m\overline{X}$, I thought it should be $\dot{X}=n \overline{X}$, but I see in fact you were correct.